# Whole word matches in jq

Tags: json, jq

Running the below:

```
$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq '. | contains(["rem"])'
```

returns `true` because "rem" is a substring of "lorem". I would like a whole word match, which would disqualify "rem" and only allow one of the three values in the input.

```
$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq 'select(. | index("rem"))'
```

returns nothing at all, but jq exits cleanly. I would have expected a `false`.

How do I get a boolean value for whole word match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to receive `true` if `any` (=at least one) of the items equals (`==`) a given value:

```bash
$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq 'any(. == "lorem")'
true

$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq 'any(. == "rem")'
false
```

In other words, you want to receive `true` if a given value is contained `IN` a set of items `.[]`:

```bash
$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq 'IN(.[]; "lorem")'
true

$ echo '["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]' | jq 'IN(.[]; "rem")'
false
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if any of the input values are in a list? Something like

`for item in [a, b, c, d]; do if item in [c, d, f]; then true; else false; fi; done`?

Think of when you're iterating through a bigger list and want to check if each value is in a smaller list

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. You can always compare both lists' items just the same way as in `$listA | any(. == $listB[])` or `IN($listA[]; $listB[])`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tripped over this many times before as well, as you'd expect it to work like this out of the box.

But the answer (if you're after a chainable exit code) is: use the `-e` flag, which, according to `man jq`:

> Sets  the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was
> neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or
> null, or  4  if  no valid  result  was  ever produced. Normally jq
> exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if
> there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

So you'd want `jq -e 'select(. | index("rem"))'`